# How can I autoplay music on my website when someone opens my webpage

Tags: html

How can I set up my website so that music begins playing automatically when a visitor opens the webpage?

I have used autoplay tag on my html but at first it worked but now its not working...

Comment: Does it throw any errors on the Console in the Inspector window?

Comment: No, music just won't play on its own I have to click the music button (which was made to make the music pause) to start the music.

Comment: can you show the code?  can you use js? Note: Chromium browsers do not allow autoplay in most cases from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. This is intrusive and considered bad practice. Browers like Chrome and Firefox took steps so it doesn't happens. You could try to find a work around (it used to be iframes but it has since been patched ) but it might hurt your SEO since this is considered bad practice.

If I visit a website and music autoplays I close the tab down and don't come back. It's bad design, please reconsider.

Have the sound muted by default and visual clues for your visitors to start playing.

Edit : Just in case I didn't make it clear. The sound not playing is not a code issue. It's the browser blocking the autoplay.

Comment: But what if its a browser based game you made

Comment: You can autoplay the music but it will be muted by default. In your game you need to make it clear that there is music that can be unmuted.